# Check if component is in view port: infinite rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to check that particular component is in view port, it seems to be working but the component is rendering infinite.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkViewPort,true);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkViewPort);
 }


 checkViewPort = () => {

    const rect = this.scrollRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    const isInview = ( rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || rect.left > window.innerWidth || 
   (rect.top) > window.innerHeight);
     this.setState({hintViewPort:!isInview});
 }
   setWrapperRef = (node) => {
    this.scrollRef = node;
 };


   <div ref = {this.setWrapper}> </div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of it rendering infinitely? I pasted your code into a sandbox and it seems to not render infinitely?

Comment: I am using preact,

Comment: I am subtracting the top -86 show that i remove the height of header